# Resolve a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to expose the functionality defined in a controller to child controllers. In essence this:

```
.state('parent', {
  controller: 'ParentCtrl',
})

.state('parent.child', {
  controller: 'ChildCtrl', // how to inject ParentCtrl?
})
```

Of course, that's not available. So how about resolving? Let's try:

```
.state('parent', {
  resolve: {
    ParentCtrl: 'ParentCtrl',
  }
})

.state('parent.child', {
  resolve: {
    ChildCtrl: 'ChildCtrl', // just declare ParentCtrl as injected dependency
  }
})
```

This doesn't work, though, if ParentCtrl or ChildCtrl are Angular controllers declared with `angular.controller`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ggHkZTkQJSsL24sm7X2V

So what if we make them services?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sl1qxWcub6bvXZfPEvHE

Hey, that works! But what if I want to inject a resolved dependency into it? Well, that doesn't work. Only one instance of the service can exist at a time anyway, and the resolved dependencies are not in scope for its creation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gsvJlJSpx2WEB1s6l7NU

It's unfortunate that ui-router will not resolve controllers. It appears the only solution is to define my controller as an `angular.constant`, then inject it into my module's `config`, and then construct a controller with a resolved dependency:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8gGKNxjpv2OgS0obNvVi

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually inject [`$controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service and return the instance of the controller during resolve. Reason is that you cannot just inject controller as is.

Example:-

```
  ParentCtrl: function($controller){
    return $controller('ParentCtrl');
  }
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yM2i0q?p=preview)**

But if it is a very commonly used functionality, then they probably should reside in the service. Also another thing is using `Controller As` syntax and you can still access them in the child controllers with the alias. There is a nice explanation [about it here](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Comment: Your demo doesn't inject `dep` into the controller like I want in my last example, but the `$controller` service is what I was looking for. I was able to get [something closer to what I wanted](http://plnkr.co/edit/IXkONlZDW7xH4kfdAjus). It is unrelated, but I'm aware `controllerAs` would let me access the parent controller from inside the child if I were to inject `$scope`, which I'm trying to avoid, for the same reasons mentioned in the article you linked.

Comment: @JohnFreeman Ofcourse you can inject any dependencies using `$controller` constructor (which is really a common usage), you did not mention that in your question. Actually i was a little confused reading your question.